# unable to redirect to response data from node js client + rest api spring boot

Tags: node.js, spring-boot

problem:
i have defined a simple index page which has 2 inputs fields, upon submit it uses
http.request(get method) in node js to call the rest api which is running as spring boot, i could able to return the response from rest api spring boot as wells as i can able to print it in the res.on.

However i need to redirect or render this data to another html **(output.htm)** page which i could not able to achieve, need your input/help on this.

**Node js (-http://localhost:8081/index.htm)**

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/grafanacpustats" method = "GET">
         Stats Name: <input type = "text" name = "statsname">  <br>
         Server Name: <input type = "text" name = "hostname">
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

**nodejs (output.htm)**

```
<html>
   <body>

         Server Name : {{ data.servername }}
         CPU Statistics : {{ data.cpu }}

   </body>
</html>
```

**ex2.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var Request = require("request");
var http = require("http");

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    resp.send("");
})

app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.htm" );
})


app.get('/stats', function (req, resp) {
   // Prepare output in JSON format
   requestParams = {
      statsname:req.query.statsname,
      hostname:req.query.hostname
   };

    console.log(req.query.statsname);
    console.log(req.query.hostname);

    var statsname = req.query.statsname;
    var hostname = req.query.hostname;
    var responseText;


    var options = {
      host: "10.96.1.17",
      port: 8080,
      path: '/CPUStatus?statsName=' + statsname + '&serverName=' + hostname,
      method: 'GET'
    };

    http.request(options, function(res) {
      console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        responseText = chunk;
      });

        //resp.send(responseText);
        resp.render(__dirname + '/output.htm', { 'data.servername': hostname , 'data.cpu' : responseText});

    }).end();


    resp.send("hello");


});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to store data in local storage or cookies and then read it in new page or pass this data by query string to another page via the URL.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this issue by  render using jade and moreover i have created a service so that block executes and awaits for response from rest api.